# Indexing Strategy in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-performance

I have a table with 2 million rows.

The ndv ( number of distinct values ) in the columns are as follows :

```
A - 3
B - 60
D - 150
E - 600,000
```

The most frequently updated columns are A & B  ( NDV = 3 for both ).

Assuming every query will have either column D or column E in WHERE clause, which of following will be the best set of indexes for SELECT statement:

```
D
D,E,A
E,A 
A,E
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough information to give a definitive assessment, but some things to consider:

1. You're unlikely to get a skip scan benefit, so if you want snappy
   response from predicates with leading E or leading D, that will be 2
   indexes.  (One leading with D, and one leading with E).
2. If A/B are updated *frequently* (although that's a generic term),
   you *might* choose to leave them out of the index definition in
   order to reduce index maintenance overhead.